# COM Error while trying to perform action on SAP application

Tags: python, com, pywin32, sap-gui

We are using Python pywin32 com library for scripting SAP GUI application running on Windows.

Things were working until yesterday.

Now, while trying to access the line of code below which performs the `maximize()`, we are getting

> com_error: (-2147417851, 'The server threw an exception.', None, None)

And getting the following error while trying to access any object in the SAP window (the last line in code).

> AttributeError: Property '.text' cannot be set.

Can someone help?  Let me know if more information is needed.

Below is the code snippet which we use to get a new scripting session, launch SAP and perform actions:

```
from subprocess import call
import win32com.client
import time

GUIPath = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/SAP/FrontEnd/SAPgui/'
WinTitle = 'SAP'
SID = 'xxxxxx.sap.xxxxx.com'
InstanceNo = 'xx'

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
cmdString = os.path.join(GUIPath, 'SAPgui.exe') + " " + SID + " " + InstanceNo
call(cmdString)
while not shell.AppActivate(WinTitle):
 time.sleep(1)

checkGUIExists = False
while not checkGUIExists:
  try:
    SAP = win32com.client.GetObject("SAPGUI").GetScriptingEngine
    session = SAP.FindById("/app/con[0]/ses[0]") # session
    checkGUIExists = True
 except:
  time.sleep(1)
 continue

//The lines failing//
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize()
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd).text = <transaction>
```

Comment: You seem to script a screen which appears after the log in screen. How do you log into your SAP system through SAP GUI? (user, password) Is it done through SSO or did you just forget this part? But anyway, to do a log in, you must also indicate the SAP "mandant" number, that I don't see here.

Comment: Yes. We do have steps to do login. I have not posted those lines here.            
 Meanwhile, I have managed to fix the issue by adding a time.sleep() for 5 seconds inside the while loop While not checkGUIExists.  Thank you

Comment: @CassianRaja so post your solution here so that it can help other folks

Comment: @Suncatcher I had earlier used maximize sap gui window within the loop where I check for the gui window to exist. Due to some latency, there is a delay in the sap window to appear. So now have added more wait time for the sap gui to exists and then perform maximize() outside of the loop.                                                                                                                                         checkifsapguiexists = false